# Vertex groups after applying mirror modifier

Tags: export, mirror, vertex-groups

I have character (with mirror mod), after that I added rig and edited weight paint and then i applyied mirror mod, now I need to export animations and character with ogre exporter but Im getting warning message that some vertex are in more then 4 vertex groups so did find one of these vertex and removed it from some vertex groups and now it is in only 2 ver. groups but again exporter saying that my vertex is in more then 4 ver. groups. I have py script which print names of groups in which my vertex is in and script print that it is in 2 groups, when I do export and run script again the scrip say that the vertex is in 6 groups but in blender the vertex is in 2 groups.
Why Im getting these two different versions of vertex groups, and can I delete older version of vertex groups if blender store them somewhere ?